# "Huge potential profit" vs. "huge profit potential"

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, word-order, modifiers

What is the proper usage — "huge potential profit" or "huge profit potential"?

Answer (score 2):

> Huge Potential Profit

We are talking about a profit. It is only a potential profit. That potential profit is huge.

> Huge Profit Potential

We are talking about a potential. That potential is for profit. That potential is huge.

They overlap, and we might sometimes use either, though there is a difference.

Most state and national lotteries have a huge potential profit, because if you do win you can receive a return of millions of times more than you spent. However, we would not describe that as a huge profit potential, because the potential covers both the likelihood and the return, and the likelihood of winning a lottery is minute.

Conversely, an investment that had a slight chance of returning a huge profit, a strong chance of doubling the amount invested in a couple of years, and only a tiny chance of not returning any profit, would have a huge profit potential, because the overall potential—considering likelihood as well as return—is huge.

As they mean different, albeit overlapping, things, either might be used, though the latter is more often how one would explain an endeavour.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice depends on what you want to say. "Huge potential profits" are profits that are huge and likely, yet uncertain. "Huge profit potential" emphasizes that the profits are very likely-- which may imply that the profits themselves would be huge.

That said, I am inclined to think that you are talking about large profits, so I would guess "huge potential profits" would be preferrable.

Answer (score 0):

> BREAK DOWN : A. Huge B. Potential C. Profit

1. ABC huge potential profit (huge: we know sth is huge. potential: we know it's not confirmed. profit: we know it's about profit. So something is huge and potential and it's about profit, that is, profit will be big and it's likely to happen or we are execting it but it's not confirmed. We don't know what will happen in the future. It's only potential.
2. ACB huge profit potential (huge: we know sth is huge. the sth can be either profit or potential 1) profit; the huge thing is profit; huge profit. potential: we know huge profit is potential and not fixed. 2) potential; huge thing is potential; the potential is huge and means profit is very likely to occur but it's not fiexed as well. 3) *addtion after initial answer* huge + profit potential (here profit potential is like one word: profit potential is huge.
3. BAC potential huge profit (potential: we know sth is potential first(not fixed). huge: it's big. profit: it's about profit. it sounds like "something is potential but the profit is huge. it sounds like a longterm project not likely to  happen for the time being. This is just my interpretation and feelings.
4. BCA potential profit huge (potential profit: expected profit, huge: which is huge; huge came at the very end of the phrase so the emphasis sequence is weak in terms of the order of the words but the speaker's capability, gestures, spell of pause and the situation can make difference.
5. CAB profit huge potential (this phrase is not constructed well and ambigue generally)
6. CBA profit potential huge (profit possibility is big. Maybe, they have been in deficit in the business; the profit potential is huge this year though it was not last year.

We have 6 number of cases (Language is not a science so the six cases can be slightly different depending on the jestures, context, intonation of the speakers and on the understanding, interpretation of the listeners and listeners' situation)

The order of the words surely would have a subtle and/or peculiar difference in its/their meaning.

But I'd like to say: Do not believe if it's potential because potential means it's subject to change. Everything changes in our world.